# Properties won't change?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

Here is my code:

```
import bge
from bge import logic

def property(controller):    
    own = controller.owner

controllor = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

target = scene.objects['Target']
ray = controllor.sensors['Ray']

if (ray.hitObject and 'Collide' in ray.hitObject and not 'Body' in ray.hitObject):
    target.worldPosition = ray.hitPosition
elif (ray.hitObject and 'Collide' in ray.hitObject and 'Body' in ray.hitObject):
    target.worldPosition = ray.hitPosition
    own['Body_Track'] = True
```

I have not finished with my code, but that is what I made so far. I am trying to make different props true and false depending on what you are aiming at: an object, and enemy (, rest WIP). This is to determine what color bullethole/blood should be added. For some reason, the last line of the code won't work. I always have issues with making multiple outcomes after an *if*. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to redesign your code:

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner

raySensor = controller.sensors['Ray']
if raySensor.positive:
    if 'Body' in raySensor.hitObject:
        target = scene.objects['Target']
        target.worldPosition = raySensor.hitPosition

    owner['Body_Track'] = True
```

Recommendations:

- Filter "Collide" at the ray sensors configuration. All hitObjects have a property called "Collide". This way you get much less hitObjects and you do not need to filter by yourself.
- No need to import *bge* and *bge.logic*. One of them should be enough.
- Writing the exact same code several times is a sign of the need to redesign the code.
- Nothing in this code ever resets the property "Body_Track". That might lead to confusion.
- No call to "property()" - this makes this function obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I don't understand why it isn't working. The code seems good to me. I have an object, which is the child of the target, and the object stays in its position. It isn't following the rays.

Comment: if the properties do not change, the above conditions are not met. Either there is no hit ("Body_Track" would not change), or the hit object has no property "Body" (case sensitive). You can find that out by adding print statements after the condition checks. e.g. print("hitObject", raySensor.hitObject)

Comment: I've checked this a million times and it won't work. I tried what you said, but it isn't working and I'm puzzled why.

Comment: can you post a demo file?

Comment: Well I don't give out my blend files but I just have an empty with a ray and script.

Comment: Ah! "from bge import logic" is the issue. I tried changing it back and it worked. Also im trying to have it make a prop "Head_Track" true by duplicating everything after if raySensor.positive: and changing the values.  It doesn't let me use elif, only if, and it makes both props true when only one should be true.

Comment: Yes you are right the import statement does not match the usage ... changed

Answer (score 0):

You have `own = controller.owner` in a function that is never called.

In the case you have shown putting `own` into a function makes it local to the function, so calling the function still won't set the variable you use later.

The easiest change would be to set `own` after you set `controller`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still isn't working.